# rosbag file size suddenly increased

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

My rosbag files have suddenly become about 10x larger for a given runtime.   I have checked and the messages are all still being published at close to the same frequency.

Is there any tool or method for examining their contents more closely to see where all of the bulk was introduced?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63247/rosbag-file-size-suddenly-increased/) by [guitardude012](https://answers.ros.org/users/4614/guitardude012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you run rosbag info?  Do your bag files contain 10x more messages?

If you haven't already, you may want to read up on the rosbag commandline parameters.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline

---

Originally posted by [mortonjt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4408/mortonjt/) with karma: 217 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1